# Trying to create an automated docker build

Tags: docker

I am trying to learn docker and create an automated build. I forked a git repo with a dockerfile. I then added this repo to my [docker hub account](https://hub.docker.com/r/sukottokun/docker-drupal-env/) as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerrepos/):

When I tried to pull it, I get:

```
$ docker pull sukottokun/docker-drupal-env
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository docker.io/sukottokun/docker-drupal-env
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/sukottokun/docker-drupal-env
```

Ok, so there is no "latest" tag, fine. After figuring out this is different than a git tag (I think, I tried and failed to clone after pushing a git tag), I am now trying to add that. Since I can't pull it, how can I add a tag?

Comment: How are you pushing the docker image up into the docker hub account?

Comment: If you look under tags, you'll see there are no tags/builds stored in that docker hub account. You need to configure the automated build settings and trigger a build or push an image to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, working on it.

Comment: Thanks @ldg that worked. I was thinking I could go from Dockerfile to Automated build w/o creating an image. It's starting to click.

Comment: Works now docker pull sukottokun/docker-drupal-env

Comment: @Scott - you can go from linked Dockerfile to automated build, you just need to set up the triggers and either commit/tag/manual trigger a build to have Docker Hub build the image.